# react native React Native IAP Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): "\"skus\" is required" issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase

I install and linked react native  React Native IAP  and also upload app in play store after that it create subscription product id But When I am request for get subscription I am getting this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bn1w.png)

[subscription product id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEPFc.png)

```
const items = Platform.select({
  ios: [
    'dev.products.gas',
    'dev.products.premium',
    'dev.products.gold_monthly',
    'dev.products.gold_yearly',
  ],
  android: ['dev.products.gas',
  'dev.products.premium',
  'dev.products.gold_monthly',
  'dev.products.gold_yearly',],
});


import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { requestPurchase, useIAP } from 'react-native-iap';

const ParchesCode = () => {
  const {
    connected,
    products,
    promotedProductsIOS,
    subscriptions,
    purchaseHistories,
    availablePurchases,
    currentPurchase,
    currentPurchaseError,
    initConnectionError,
    finishTransaction,
    getProducts,
    getSubscriptions,
    getAvailablePurchases,
    getPurchaseHistories,
  } = useIAP();

  const handlePurchase = async (sku) => {
    await requestPurchase({ sku });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... listen to currentPurchaseError, to check if any error happened
  }, [currentPurchaseError]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... listen to currentPurchase, to check if the purchase went through
  }, [currentPurchase]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
      <Button
        title="Get the products"
        onPress={() => getSubscriptions(items)}
      />

      {subscriptions.map((product) => (
        <View key={product.productId}>
          <Text>{product.productId}</Text>

          <Button
            title="Buy"
            onPress={() => handlePurchase(product.productId)}
          />


        </View>
      ))}
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(connected)}</Text>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(connected)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ParchesCode;
```

I am not getting subscriptions when I am calling getSubscriptions() function. I need result after calling this but I am getting error like that -> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
skus is required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is with working example. there issue is due to change in code but the documentation is not updated.

Here is the product list. the code only for iOS.

```
import {requestPurchase, useIAP, withIAPContext} from 'react-native-iap';
    const myProducts = [
      'product.example.1',
      'product.example.2',
    ];
const InAppPurchaseScreen = ({navigation}) => {
     useEffect(() => {
           getProductsAndPurchases();
     }, []);
    const getProductsAndPurchases = async () => {
       try {
         await getProducts({skus: myProducts});
       } catch (error) {
         //console.log("Products error: ", error)
       }
    };

}
export default withIAPContext(InAppPurchaseScreen);
```

Comment: Thanks man , I was trying from 2 days

Comment: you are welcome. same I done this in 7 days. :(

Comment: Can you give me  requestSubscription code man ?  I do this like that const handlePurchase = async (sku) => {
     try {

     const result =  await requestSubscription({skus:[sku]});
     console.log(result)
      
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
     }
  };

Comment: const purchaseItemSearch = async () => {
    setCheckingPayment(true);
    try {
      await requestPurchase({
        sku: 'product1.example.1',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(error)
      setCheckingPayment(false);
      setCancelPurchase(true);
    }
  };

Comment: I add this code but I am getting same error.                                                                                  const purchaseItemSearch = async () => {
    try {
      await requestPurchase({ sku: 'com.mylocal.mounthly', });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    };
  }.                                                                                                                                                 [Error: skus is required for Android purchase]

Comment: try with skus property. or may be some issue with your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, here is a working example of react-native-iap with latest version.

```
import {  initConnection, getSubscriptions, requestSubscription } from 'react-native-iap';

const products = ['example_799_1m', 'example_1100_3m'];

useEffect(() => {
 initConnection()
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('error connecting to store...');
  })
  .then(() => {
    getSubscriptions({skus: products})
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('error finding products');
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('products with offerToken', res);
        // store/handle response
      });
  });
}, []);

const handleRequestSubscription = () => {
   requestSubscription({
      sku: productId,
      ...(offerToken && {
         subscriptionOffers: [
           {
             sku: productId,          // as a string
             offerToken: offerToken,  // as a string
           },
         ],
      }),
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log('error buying product', err);
     })
    .then(async res => {
      console.log('request subscription ',JSON.stringify(res));
      // handle/store response
    });
}
```

- "react-native-iap": "^12.4.12",
- React Native: 0.70.6